# O que está errado meu programa para não estar a dar o output do objeto da estrutura?

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 30
#define N_DISCIPLINAS 5
#define N_CHARDISCIPLINAS 30
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */


typedef struct
{
    char nome[MAX];
    int nAluno;
    char disciplinas[N_DISCIPLINAS][N_CHARDISCIPLINAS];
}Estudante;

void mostraAluno(Estudante *aluno);

//MAIN
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    Estudante *aluno1;
    aluno1 = malloc(sizeof(Estudante));
    strcpy(aluno1->nome, "Tomás Oom");
    aluno1->nAluno = 11092719;
    strcpy(aluno1->disciplinas[0], "Matemática");
    strcpy(aluno1->disciplinas[1], "Ética");
    strcpy(aluno1->disciplinas[2], "HCP");
    strcpy(aluno1->disciplinas[3], "Programação Avançada");
    strcpy(aluno1->disciplinas[4], "Redes e Comunicações");
    
    mostraAluno(&aluno1);
    
    return 0;
}

void mostraAluno(Estudante *aluno)
{
    int i;
    aluno = malloc(sizeof(Estudante));
    printf("ALUNO:\n");
    printf("Nome: %s", aluno->nome);
    printf("\n NºAluno: %d", aluno->nAluno);
    printf("\nDisciplinas:\n");
    for(i = 0; i<N_DISCIPLINAS; i++)
    {
        printf("\t %s", aluno->disciplinas[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite!

Há basicamente dois erros no seu código. O primeiro é na hora de passar a estrutura como argumento na função. Observe:

```
// Sua função pede um endereço de uma struct
void mostraAluno(Estudante *aluno);
```

Quando você cria o ponteiro e aloca memória, `Estudante *aluno1;` e `aluno1 = malloc(sizeof(Estudante));`, então `aluno1` aponta para um endereço de uma estrutura, sendo assim não é preciso o `&` como argumento. Basta colocar:

```
// Aqui está correto
mostraAluno(aluno1);

// Aqui está errado
// Ao fazer isso, você está passando o endereço
// do ponteiro que aponta para a estrutura e não o endereço
// da estrutura
mostraAluno(&aluno1);
```

O segundo erro é fazer outro `malloc` no seu programa. Repare que `aluno` já está apontando para uma estrutura e quando você faz `aluno = malloc(sizeof(Estudante));`, o `aluno` para de apontar para essa estrutura e passa a apontar para uma outra que você acabou de criar. Basta remover `aluno = malloc(sizeof(Estudante));` para corrigir esse problema.